# How to read a value with out know father node Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I whant to get values of the node `7NmECb...` without knowing what is the node father.

I just know how to get value like this:

```
private void recuperarPedidos(){

    DatabaseReference produtosRef = dReference
            .child("empresa")
            .child( "Farmacia")
            .child(UsuarioFirebase.getIdUsuario());


    produtosRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            empresas.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                empresas.add( ds.getValue(Empresa.class) );
            }

            categoria = empresas.get(0).getCategoria();


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: So what's wrong with this code?

Comment: i whant to get child (UsuarioFirebase.getIdUsuario()) with out pass a .child( "Farmacia")

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way you can use a query in Firebase realtime database, to get an objects two level deep without having the full path. There is a solution, in which you can add a listener on `empresa` node and use `getValue()` method. It returns a `Map<String, Object>` but is not recommended since you are getting all data within that node. With other words, it's a waste of bandwidth and resources. One solution might be to change your database structure by adding the `empresa` node as a property of your user object.

I will provide you the code that can help you get that object but I encourage you to find a more appropriate database schema which is more oriented to the queries you want to perform.

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference empresaRef = rootRef.child("empresa");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) ds.getValue();
            //Iterate through the map and get the results
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
empresaRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```